# Simply connected in the complex plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $V = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : \vert x \vert \leq 1 , \vert y \vert = 1 \} $. Prove that $\mathbb{C}^2 - V $ is simply connected.

Any help with this problem, please?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have any intuition about what $X=\mathbb{C}^2-V$ looks like?  You might try writing a closed loop $\rho\colon S^1\to X$ in terms of its coordinate functions, and then try writing an explicit homotopy of $\rho$ with the constant path.

Answer (score 0):

Hint/Sketch:

The space is obviously path connected (just draw a path around the removed region).  Now, use the fact that we can homotope any closed loop around the removed region to contract it (think of removing a ball from $\mathbb{R}^3$) so $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^2-V)=\{1\}$.  It may take a bit of work to write this down formally.

Equivalently, we can see that $\mathbb{C}^2-V$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{C}^2-\{(0,0)\}$.  Then just use the prior observation about $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a point.